# How to show generalize function from Pressable in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I am doing simple Android app that have to show content of variable on screen and I have component that appends string to existing variable. In function App I have:

```
export default function App() {
    const [getNumber, setNumber] = useState('');
    return (
        <>
            <View style={styles.numbers}>
                <Text>
                   {getNumber}
                </Text>
            </View>
            <Pressable style={styles.key} onPress={function(){
            setNumber(getNumber => getNumber + 'addition');
            }}>
                <Text>Add</Text>
            </Pressable>
        ...
        </>
    );
}
```

This implementation works but when I try to extract and generalize function from `Pressable`

```
export default function App() {
    const [getNumber, setNumber] = useState('');

    funtion addString(stringToAdd){
        setNumber(getNumber + stringToAdd);
    }
    return(
        <>
        ...
            <Pressable style={styles.key} onPress={addNumber('addition')}>
                <Text>Add</Text>
            </Pressable>
        ...
        </>
    );
}
```

this does not work. It says i am re-rendering to React's limits.

I want to generalize because I have 12 `Pressable`. I am not into React and Javascript so I am missing something for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling that `addString` right away and updating state when rendering the component. You can make it lazy by returning function that will do the updating.

```
function addString(stringToAdd) {
    return () => setNumber(number => number + stringToAdd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `addString` function directly on initialization in `onPress` method like

```
onPress={addString('addition')}
```

This will unnecessarily call the `addString` function on every re-render.
Instead of calling it like that, do it like below

```
onPress={()=>addString('addition')}
```

Note the `()=>`.

This will call the `addString` method only when the button is being pressed.